# How to configure a self hosted agent from one ADO organisation to another ADO organisation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Can we configure a self hosted agent from one organisation to another organisation?

Is it possible by azure rest api.

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how you understand the self-host agent of Azure DevOps. What do you mean by 'configure a self-hosted agent from one ADO organization to another ADO organization', do you mean to download the agent file from an organization, and then configure it to another organization?

If so, then your idea is no problem.

Follow Below steps it will tell you how to configure agent:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent

Which organization the agent will be configured for is based on the organization url you give, not related to other things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install multiple parallel agents on the same self-hosted server and configure them to connect to different organizations. But one single agent can only connect to one organization.

Just unpack the agent zip file to two different folders and configure each one with the organization URLs, authentication method and other settings.

This way you get two agent services running side by side serving the two organizations.